# The dotted lines in the given matrix are not aligning properly

Tags: nicematrix

Using the nicematrix package and the following code,

```
\begin{document}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}[![enter image description here][1]][1]
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
$\begin{bNiceMatrix}
1 & -\dfrac{1}{a} & -\dfrac{1}{b} & & \Cdots & -\dfrac{1}{c} \\
-\dfrac{1}{d} & 1 & -\dfrac{1}{e} & \Ddots & & \Vdots \\
-\dfrac{1}{f} & -\dfrac{1}{g} & 1 & \Ddots & & \\
& \Ddots & \Ddots & \Ddots & & -\dfrac{1}{h} \\
\Vdots & & & & & -1/n \\
-\dfrac{1}{i} & \Cdots & &   -\dfrac{1}{j} & -\dfrac{1}{k} & 1
\end{bNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

I get the following image

[image]

The idea was to create long dotted lines between certain numbers, but the dotted lines keep going all over the place every time I try running the code. I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The working example code you have posted is incomplete. The `bNicematrix` environment code should be inside `begin{document} ... \end{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

Just rewriting the code you have posted in the correct way as an answer, instead of a comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document} % should start after all packages have been introduced
$\begin{bNiceMatrix}
1 & -\dfrac{1}{a} & -\dfrac{1}{b} & & \Cdots & -\dfrac{1}{c} \\
-\dfrac{1}{d} & 1 & -\dfrac{1}{e} & \Ddots & & \Vdots \\
-\dfrac{1}{f} & -\dfrac{1}{g} & 1 & \Ddots & & \\
& \Ddots & \Ddots & \Ddots & & -\dfrac{1}{h} \\
\Vdots & & & & & -1/n \\
-\dfrac{1}{i} & \Cdots & &   -\dfrac{1}{j} & -\dfrac{1}{k} & 1
\end{bNiceMatrix}$
\end{document}
```

[image: Nicematrix-]